# search textbox problem - fails when two of the same words are present

Tags: c#, search, richtextbox

I'm trying to highlight all instances of words in a rich text box. I have been using the find method, but that finds the first instance.

I would like to start the first search at startPos = 0, then when I find an instance, start the new search from the last char of the found instance i.e.

`newStartPos = (rtb.Text.IndexOf(text, type) + rtb.Text.Length);`

any ideas...

Basically I need to find all instances of words in a list container as the user types into a richtextbox, for every hit I change the word colour within RTB and then do some maths on the chars within the complete RTB depending on the number of hits

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload [`string.IndexOf(string, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx), as `startIndex` you use `lastFoundIndex + 1`